# Opening and saving files in a folder

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, parsing, data-structures

I have a directory of files that I want to convert their contents to all lower-case valued.
For a specific file, this works fine:

```
with open(r'specific_file_directory', 'r') as file:
    # Read the file into a string
    text = file.read()
    # Use the string's lower() method to make everything lowercase
    text = text.lower()
    print(text)
    # Split text by whitespace into list of words
    word_list = text.split()
```

But, I want to do this for every file in my folder - is it possible?

Additionally, after doing this, I also want to save the file names to a CSV in a column.

For this: I tried (Separately):

```
import os, csv
f=open("C:\directory\file.csv",'r+')
w=csv.writer(f)
for path, dirs, files in os.walk("C:\directory"):
    for filename in files:
        w.writerow(C:\directory\file.csv)
```

But for this I get an error message:

> SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your problem lies in the loop

```
for path, dirs, files in os.walk("C:\directory"):
for filename in files:
    w.writerow(C:\directory\file.csv)
```

The "EOL while scanning string literal" is in the os.walk() call - since you're using Windows, you'll need to escape the `\`. For your output, if you specify the full path to the file then you should expect to have to escape any `\` in the path too.

It might make more sense to `os.chdir("C:\\directory")` and then use

```
for _path, _dirs, files in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
```